# RecyclerView Drawer Not Clicking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout, recyclerview-layout

I have built a custom navigation drawer with recyclerview and burger menu by myself. I created the interface for handling item clicks and also the ItemTouchHelper class but the drawer items are not responding to click events, only rapidly closes the drawer.

I have also tried setting the click events in the adapter but still same situation. Here's my code:

Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerDrawerHolder> {

private final Context context;
private List<DrawerItems> itemsList;

private String decodedImage;
private SharedPreferences imagePrefs;

private final ConnectionDetector detector;

public RecyclerDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<DrawerItems> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    detector = new ConnectionDetector(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerDrawerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_menu_items_layout, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerDrawerHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerDrawerHolder viewholder, final int position) {
    DrawerItems drawerItems = itemsList.get(position);
    viewholder.menuTitleTV.setText(drawerItems.getTitleTxt());

    if (!detector.isConnected()){
        getImageFromPrefs();
    } else {
        fetchUserImageOnline();
    }

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(drawerItems.getIconImg())
            .into(viewholder.menuIcon);

    //viewholder.badgeCountTV.setText(drawerItems.getBadgeCount());
    viewholder.badgeCountTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    viewholder.setClickListener(new RecyclerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyProfileActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ChatsActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyHugsActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ChatCirclesActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class));
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}

private void fetchUserImageOnline() {

}

private void getImageFromPrefs() {
    imagePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("ImagePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    decodedImage = imagePrefs.getString("image_user", null);

    RecyclerDrawerHolder holder = null;
    if (!decodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") || !decodedImage.isEmpty()){
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(decodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap userBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        if (userBitmap != null){


            holder.menuIcon.setImageBitmap(userBitmap);
        } else {
            holder.menuIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person_avatar));
        }
    }

}

}
```

My activity code for setting up the recyclerview and handling click events:

```
private void setUpDrawer() {
    recyclerDrawer.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerDrawer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //DrawerItems drawerItems = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.send_round, "Profile", 99);
    DrawerItems drawerItems = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.send_round, "Profile", 99);
    itemsList.add(drawerItems);

    DrawerItems drawerItems2 = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.chats, "Chats", 80);
    itemsList.add(drawerItems2);

    DrawerItems drawerItems3 = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.hugs, "Hugs",90);
    itemsList.add(drawerItems3);

    DrawerItems drawerItems4 = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.chat_circles, "Chat Circles", 67);
    itemsList.add(drawerItems4);

    DrawerItems drawerItems5 = new DrawerItems(R.drawable.settings, "Settings", 0);
    itemsList.add(drawerItems5);

    drawerAdapter = new RecyclerDrawerAdapter(this, itemsList);
    recyclerDrawer.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.burger_menu);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                //setClickListener();
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });

    setDrawerClickListener();

}

private void setDrawerClickListener() {
    recyclerDrawer.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemTouchListener(this, recyclerDrawer, new RecyclerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Profile Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "PersonalChat Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "My Hugs Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "ChatCircles Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Settings Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
}

private void initWidgets() {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    displayMsgsRV = findViewById(R.id.home_messagesRV);
    recyclerDrawer = findViewById(R.id.recyclerDrawer);
    home_inputMsgTET = findViewById(R.id.home_inputMsgTET);
    send_msg_iv = findViewById(R.id.send_msg_iv);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    setUpDrawer();

    send_msg_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

    //getPublicMessages();

}
```

Here's my layout file as suggested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">   

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerDrawer"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/black" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
       android:id="@+id/containerFrag"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

DrawerItems is my model class. Please guys help out I don't seem to know why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the layout that has the `<DrawerLayout>` in it.

Comment: @MikeM., have a look now

Comment: The drawer `View` - the `LinearLayout`, in this case - needs to be listed last within the `DrawerLayout`. Move it to after the `FrameLayout`. Also, that `LinearLayout` isn't necessary, unless you're going to put something else in it. If not, you could just make the `RecyclerView` itself the drawer. If you want to keep the `LinearLayout`, you should change its `layout_width` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks again bruh!!! If you could post ur comment as an answer, I'll be very happy to accept it. Thank you soo much

Comment: What you can do is implement click listener using interface in your Activity. That will make your work very easy.

Comment: Yes, I have used that. Thanks all

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty common issue, so I'll just mark it as a duplicate, since I myself have answered it a few times already. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!